# PhantomJS - Resource redirection causes an request error

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I get a "resource request error" when a resource in https redirects to an http resource. This error prevents to get the html content.

example :

```
phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=yes --debug=true  phantom-script.js 
http://io9.com/the-milky-way-flows-into-the-sea-170738633

    2015-05-28T12:08:51 [DEBUG] Network - Resource request error: 5 ( 
"Operation canceled" ) URL: "https://kinja.com/api/profile/getsession?redirect=http%3A%2F
%2Fio9.com%2Fsetsession%3Fr%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fio9.com%252Fthe-milky-
way-flows-into-the-sea-1707386330"
    = onResourceError()
```

How to handle this kind of error?

Comment: Have you tried to add --web-security=false ?

Comment: I get the same error with --web-security=false

Comment: What about --ssl-protocol=any ? What phantomjs version do you have?

Comment: the same error  with --ssl-protocol=any. The version of phantomjs  is 2.0.0